# Smichut or Noun and adjective in Lashon remiya (Tehilim 120)

Tags: grammar-dikduk, tehilim-psalms

In [Tehilim 120:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.120.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and [3](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.120.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) we find *lashon remiya* (לשון רמייה) where *lamed* has *qamets:*

> יְֽהוָ֗ה הַצִּ֣ילָה נַ֭פְשִׁי מִשְּׂפַת־שֶׁ֑קֶר **מִלָּשׁ֥וֹן רְמִיָּֽה**׃ מַה־יִּתֵּ֣ן לְ֭ךָ וּמַה־יֹּסִ֥יף לָ֗ךְ **לָשׁ֥וֹן רְמִיָּֽה**׃

> O *Hashem,* deliver my soul from lying lips, from a **deceitful tongue.** What shall be given unto thee, and what shall be done more unto thee, thou **deceitful tongue?**

Logically we would expect *sheva,* because it is understood as *smichut* *(remiya* is a noun and not an adjective). Why does *lashon* act as in status absolutus? Is there a possibility, that *remiya* could be an adjective (none of vocabularies or concordances bring this option). Biblia Hebraica (Kittel ed.) has a remark that Aquila (Onkelos?) has *leshon* with *sheva.* Any suggestions how is this grammatically possible?

Comment: [It seems that JPS considers it as an adjective and links to the root רמ"ה]

Comment: similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30605/170